# "Can't use string ("Catalyst::Authentication::Store:"...) as a HASH ref while "strict refs"

Tags: perl, perl-module, catalyst

i setup the Catalyst::Plugin::Authorization::Abilities module from this link:

[http://search.cpan.org/dist/Catalyst-Plugin-Authorization-Abilities/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/Authorization/Abilities.pm][1]

Bur when call this function:

$c->assert_user_ability('show_home_action');

I got this message prob:

Caught exception in OpConsole::Controller::Root->index "Can't use string ("Catalyst::Authentication::Store:"...) as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at accessor Catalyst::Authentication::Store::DBIx::Class::User::_user (defined at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/Catalyst/Authentication/Store/DBIx/Class/User.pm line 12) line 5."

i check few times my configuration and it seem to me that's all ok. but what's the prob :/

Comment: So you are saying that you have copied the entire `sub delete : Local {...` and `sub display_user : Local {...` functions into a blank perl script and are getting this error?  Perhaps you could post some of the code so it is easier to see the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the prob, it was a wrong configuration in the database (in UserAction table i had wrong field name  ("actio_id" => "action_id")). so every thx is ok now :p

Answer (score 1):

Usually this error message means you've used something that was meant to be an object method as if it were a class method.

```
use v5.14;

package Foo {
   use Moose;
   has foo => (is => 'ro', default => 42);
}

my $class  = 'Foo';
my $object = $class->new;

say $object->foo;  # 42
say $class->foo;   # Can't use string ("Foo") as a HASH ref...
```

This is because the `foo` method (which is generated by Moose in the above example) is implemented something like this:

```
sub foo {
   my $self = shift;
   return $self->{foo};
}
```

So it treats the first parameter (`$self`) as a hash ref. If the method is called like `$class->foo`, then `$class` which is a string, is treated like a hash ref, which is disallowed by `strict "refs"`.